# Dokku Nginx Serve Static Files

Tags: node.js, nginx, dokku

I'm trying to set up the deployment for a node.js webapp on dokku. However, the root path of my app only needs to serve static html, css, and javascript and all other routes "/api/..." should be sent to my node app which is running on port 5000. I've tried to set this up with the following nginx.ssl.conf.template:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path /var/tmp;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    upstream ceresshop_api {
      server 127.0.0.1:5000;
      keepalive 64;
}
server {
  listen      [::]:$NGINX_PORT;
  listen      $NGINX_PORT;
  server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;
  return 301 https://\$host:$NGINX_SSL_PORT\$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen      [::]:$NGINX_SSL_PORT ssl spdy;
  listen      $NGINX_SSL_PORT ssl spdy;
  server_name $SSL_SERVER_NAME;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;
$SSL_DIRECTIVES

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  add_header          Alternate-Protocol  $NGINX_SSL_PORT:npn-spdy/2;
  location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
         root /data/public;
         access_log off;
         expires max;
       }
  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://$APP;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port \$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start \$msec;
  }
  include $DOKKU_ROOT/$APP/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

however, I'm not sure where to point the "root" parameter of

```
location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascripts/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|index.html) {
         root /data/public;
         access_log off;
         expires max;
       }
```

since the app is being deployed with dokku. For context, the files that I'm trying to static serve with ngix are in the "public" director of my app directory.

Comment: If you want serve static sites without create a new container compatible with Dokku try https://github.com/pahaz/static-site-paas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nginx configuration is *outside* of the container, and thus does not have access to the static files inside of your container.

If you want, you can move those files to a mounted volume in your container, and then point nginx to that mounted volume. Otherwise, your application will need to serve them in whatever way node applications normally do so. I would look into seeing what the nodejs buildpack from heroku prescribes as the best option.

Comment: I tried to mount the public folder in my app directory using dokku's docker options feature so that the docker options equate to: `Deploy options:
    -v /home/dokku/public:/app/public
Run options:
    -v /home/dokku/public:/app/public` but when I ls the /home/dokku/public folder after deploying my project, the directory is empty.

Comment: Files that were already in that directory aren't copied out of the directory onto the host when you use docker options. You'd need to somehow handle copying the files onto that directory during the deploy process.